# after install auth2.0 server Laravel5.1 give an server error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.1

I have successfully installed Laravel5.1
`localhost/myproject/public` link is working well.

After that I installed Auth2.0 server accroding to this.
https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/97496916713af20b4594dee2d867168464d56316/docs/getting-started/laravel-5.md

After install and configure I called the url `http://localhost/myproject/public/oauth/access_token`
and its giving `500 server error` for all the url with `http://localhost/myproject/public`

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: did you check the error log

Comment: Yes.checked and now I found the error.my mistake.syntax error.Thanks !

Comment: I would highly recommend that you don't start your Laravel `5.x` projects on Laravel `5.1`, and instead use `5.2`. There are  many important differences between the two, and they're too big to overlook on newer projects.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.Can I please know the main draw back or reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

From your link:

In order to make some the authorization and resource server work correctly with Laravel5, remove the App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken line from the $middleware array and place it in the $routeMiddleware array like this: 'csrf' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

```
Note: remember to add the csrf middleware manually on any route where it's appropriate.
```

Hope these are followed.

Comment: yes.Thanks for the reply.I missed a `]` in outh2.php.now it solved.